# MAC address regex pattern on HTML form does not work

Tags: html, forms

I have an text input inside a html form, I expected it to validate MAC addresses (using the "pattern" attribute), but it will let pass anything uppon clickig the submit button...

```
<form>
/*stuff...*/
<input type="text" id="p1_mac" name="p1_mac" pattern="^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$" maxlength="17" required/>
/*stuff...*/
<input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
</form>
```

This behaviour can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/a53jtvxp/

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the validation logic on that input? (The code you’ve provided doesn’t event include a form element).

Comment: I did a simple check on https://regex101.com/r/OuIkyY/1 to fix your validation case for a complete IPv6 address (i.e. without omitting zeros). The actual validation has to come up with that cases too.

Comment: @Quentin the input element is contained inside a form and there's a submit button in the end of the form. The pattern attribute should do the validation uppon clicking the submit button.

Comment: @Niloct I add a fiddle demonstration link on my question, the behaviour can be verified there.

Comment: I don't think you need to use the `^`, which would mean the start of a line. The other aspect is that each browser may have a different regex, and there's nothing to keep someone from using postman or cURLing into your form, so really you should be extra sure to have a backend validation.

Comment: @strange_bakery I meant that you need to modify your regular expression for it to work even in the most parseable case, which is the full IPv6 address. Compare the regular expression I posted on my comment link with yours.

Comment: @Niloct I'm parsing MAC adresses, not IP adresses (i.e. DataLink Layer, not Network layer)...

Comment: @strange_bakery sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes: the pattern although seemed valid for MAC addresses had a compilation error, because you had to escape the dash: `[:\-]` instead of `[:-]`.

Then you don't need a `onsubmit` for validation triggering. You need to add an event listener to the `invalid` event on **each** form element (i.e. not on the form itself), when using the `pattern` html5 validation attribute.

Then, if the element is invalid, you cancel the submit inside the `invalid` handler with `event.preventDefault();`.

Check the snippet below, it will post to google if you enter a valid MAC address, or alert a message if you do not.

```js
    document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('invalid', function(event) {
        alert("Validation didn't pass!");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

```html
<form action="https://google.com">
    <input type="text" name="formField" title="Enter MAC address" pattern="^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:\-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```